# How to disable graphql playground?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql, graphql-playground

My angular application is configured with graphql which by default enabled with playground, how to disable it? following is my
**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.8",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.8",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.3.4",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^7.0.8",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "graphql": "^14.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0"
  }
```

and **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16
RUN mkdir -p /testappservice/app

COPY dist/apps/testappservice-container testappservice/app
COPY apps/testappservice/build/docker/package.json testappservice

WORKDIR /testappservice
RUN yarn install

ENV PORT 80
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED 0
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD ["node", "app/index.js"]
```

app module added with playground set to false but it is still enabled **app.module.ts**

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground:false,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), './apps/testappservice/src/graphql.schema.ts'),
      },
      dataSources: () => {
        return {
          xyzAPI: new XYZAPI(),
          abcAPI: new ABCAPI(),
        };
      },
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    }),
    ABCModule,
    XYZModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `GraphQlModule`'s options, set `playground: false`.

`app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      playground: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
      ...otherOptions
    }),
    ...otherImports,
  ],
  ...otherModuleMetadata
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you please share code samples and filename in your post?

Comment: I have updated original post with your recommendation but no luck playground still works, the playground web app resolves at /graphql uri app loads. with the playground set to false should disable playground hence /graphql should not be resolved. Not why!

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce this?

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce this, i need to isolate this into another sample app.. Any possible bug in underlaying packages? FYI, i have updated app module code in the original post, also is there any possible way to restrict /graphql uri at deployment level or via dockerfile ets?